# How to deploy built RestApi using NodeJs and Mogodb as DB in the localhost to AWS? RestApi is for Mobile App written in flutter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a Rest Api using Node.js and Mongodb, willing to deploy this somewhere, So I have chosen AWS for this. So, how to deploy it and **I will be calling that Api** from my Flutter mobile app for **GeoSpatial** data, which will be stored in **mongodb**. While deploying I have two options like **AWS Elastic Beanstalk and AWS EC2 instance which to choose?** and how to deploy the Node.js and mongodb into them.

**(If someone feels something wrong with this question can suggest edit)**

*P.S: Thanks for the help in Advance :)*

Comment: It is better to check `heroku` for deployments instead of aws because they provide pipelines and auto deployment features.

Comment: @Ahmad, what is pipeline ? and thanks for the reply..

Comment: pipeline means they provide you to setup multiple environments like staging and production and your code goes into pipeline, first deployed to staging then to production.
if you don't want to setup pipeline, just a simple app, they also provide this. you can host your node app on heroku.

Comment: Main advantage of heroku is that it gets integrated with github and allows you to auto deploy an app on every commit on specific branch

Comment: if i use heroku as my hosting for rest api, then where to host my mongodb?

Comment: you can use heroku addon to host your mongodb, either mlab mongodb or objectrocket mongodb